# Identify font for the logo of the French website "Psychologies.com"

Tags: fonts, font-identification, typefaces

I am trying to find the fonts used in the following Logo for the French website "Psychologies.com". I've been trying to use whatthefont.com, but haven't had much success.

[image: Psychologies]

Comment: Your font-identification attempts don't seem very successful, this is your 9th question in a row. Please try to exhaust your available tools before asking new ones, as these are not really contributing to the site. We don't mind helping, but it sounds like we are doing your job for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps http://www.dafont.com/bebas-neue.font?text=PSYCHOLOGIES.COM ?

[image]

or perhaps Roboto Condensed at http://www.google.com/fonts ?
They are both free.